# Tumblr API - exclude results by tag

Tags: json, api, jsonp, tumblr

I'm making a site whose feed runs off of tumblr. There's one section for general posts and another section for "featured" posts, which is specified by tag (ie `#featured`).

I'm trying to prevent the same post from showing up in two different spots on the same page, so for my general feed section, is there a way to have it **exclude** posts with `#featured`?

Answer (score 0):

When you get the post object for processing you can always check

```
if(!in_array($tag_to_exclude, $post->tags)) {
    // Post does not contain tag - display ...
}
```

I'm guessing you grab the `$apidata->response->posts` and run a `foreach` loop? Otherwise feel free to ask for more info

Comment: Yeah i guess that would work, was wondering if there was an api call but the result will be the same. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry man I don't think they bothered with an omit tag query -> you can use this to sort the posts from the api by building an array of tagged posts and sending the rest into another array for the general feed. If you're wanting to sort out more tags you can use this method to just build more arrays containing omitted tags - best solution I imagine there is for this :)

Answer (score 0):

I've been trying to accomplish the same thing and had no luck with the Tumblr API. Seems strange they don't have this feature, but I guess that's how it is. I did write a PHP class that will accomplish this though, which might be of help to the OP or anyone else looking to do the same thing.

```
class Tumblr {
    private $api_key = 'your_tumblr_api_key';
    private $api_version = 2;
    private $api_uri = 'api.tumblr.com';
    private $blog_name = 'your_tumblr_blog_name';

    private $excluded = 0;
    private $request_total = 0;

    public function get_posts($count = 40, $offset = 0) {
        return json_decode(file_get_contents($this->get_base_url() . 'posts?limit=' . $count . '&offset=' . $offset . $this->get_api_key()), TRUE)['response']['posts'];
    }

    /*
     * Recursive function that can make multiple requests to retrieve
     * the $count number of posts that do not have a tag equal to $tag.
     */
    public function get_posts_without_tag($tag, $count, $offset) {
        $excluded = 0;

        // get the the set of posts, hoping they won't have the tag
        $posts = $this->get_posts($count, $offset);
        foreach ($posts as $key => $post) {
            if (in_array($tag, $post['tags'])) {
                unset($posts[$key]);
                $excluded++;
            }
        }
        // if the full $count hasn't been retrieved, call this function recursively
        if ($excluded > 0) {
            $posts = array_merge($posts, $this->get_posts_without_tag($tag, $excluded, $offset + $count));
        }

        return $posts;
    }

    private function get_base_url() {
        return 'http://' . $this->api_uri . '/v' . $this->api_version . '/blog/' . $this->blog_name . '.tumblr.com/';
    }

    private function get_api_key() {
        return '&api_key=' . $this->api_key;
    }
}
```

The `get_posts_without_tag()` function is where most of the action happens. It unfortunately solves the problem by making multiple requests. Just be sure to replace `$api_key` and `$blog_name` with the your API key and blog name.